# Errors when using CDN Sync Tool plugin

Tags: plugins, cdn, sync

Now that wp-supercache has some built in support for CDNs, I've tried using the CDN Sync Tool to do an initial upload of files to Cloudfront.

But, I'm getting 2 sets of errors when syncing (I'm having to use force upload, as for some reason CDN Sync Tool thinks all my files have been uploaded already).

1. cURL error: Failed to open/read local data from file/application (26)
   This error isn't actually preventing the files from being uploaded though
2. [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Too many open files in /var/www/xxxxx/wp-content/plugins/cdn-sync-tool/lib/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php
   This error does stop files from being uploaded -> S3.

So, the 2nd error occurs after a certain (changeable) number of files have been uploaded, and then affects all remaining uploads.

Any ideas why or what can be done?

[Update]

After updating to version 0.9, am now getting the following errors repeatedly (after about 2000 files have been synced)

> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in [filepath]/lib/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php on line 276
>
> The stream size for the streaming upload cannot be determined. done
>
> Syncing [2411/4732] img2343435.jpg
>
> Warning: fopen(/var/www/xx/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/mg2343435.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: 
>       No such file or directory in [filepath]/lib/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php on line 527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS you running? As this actually sounds like an AWS php sdk issue. Having a look though their source code shows they don't seem to use fclose and your OS must have a limit on open files.

If you email me at iain.cambridge - at - fubra.com I'll send you a copy of the sdk with a bug fix aswell.

Comment: If possible, it would be very helpful if you could post that bug fix here (or post it elsewhere and link to there) so others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: @Backie - Ubuntu 9.04. `ulimit -a` shows that open files is set to the default (1024). I'll increase this to 4096 and see if the error repeats. Any idea about the initial curl error?

Comment: @anu - added fclose to aws sdk copy and be found https://github.com/icambridge/aws-sdk-for-php also seems that the curl Error is just because the post fields are empty. I have no idea why.

Comment: Actually seems all that needs done is upgrade the aws-sdk-for-php as the core one has a fix and my fork's fix is redundant. I'll release an updated version of the plugin tomorrow with the new sdk version.

Comment: @Backie - tested the latest version (0.9b), and still getting multiple upload errors, but a slightly different error message now - I'll update the question with the new error.

Comment: Hmm I've done a quick bug fix on the aws sdk request core to check it is an actual file resource, the file can be downloaded at http://iain.at/7 if you replace the lib/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php with that file and rerun and let me know what the result is. Thanks. Also does the file it can't read actually exist?

Comment: Apologies, haven't had time to look at this. I'm going to accept your answer, and add a todo item for myself to get on this next week!